# Ruby on Rails RSpec Request Spec: Cannot pass params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Having a bit of difficulty getting my auth spec passing for an api I'm building in Rails.

My spec looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'POST /login', type: :request do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:url) { '/login' }
  let(:params) do
    {
      user: {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }
    }
  end

  context 'when params are correct' do
    before do
      post url, params: params
    end

    it 'returns 200' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
...
```

However when I try to run this, it gives me the following error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`

When I use pry to go in and debug it, the `params` variable resolves to the correct hash: `{:user=>{:username=>"MyString", :email=>"mystring", :password=>"fooBar"}}` and the url is correct as well: `"/login"`

It also fails to work when using the hash itself instead of the variable like so: `post url, params: {:user=>{:username=>"MyString", :email=>"mystring", :password=>"fooBar"}}`

However what's weird is that I can pass something like `{:user=>'hello'}` and it will run, albeit also returning a 401 error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the full stack of the error?  It should give you some indication of which line is generating the error.

Comment: In Rails 4 you can pass params as positional arguments to the request methods for example (`post url, { foo: "bar" }, { notice: 'Hello world' }, { user_id: 1 }`). This is depreciated in Rails 5 which requires keyword arguments  `post url, params: { foo: "bar" }, flash: { notice: 'Hello world' }, session: { user_id: 1 }`. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html

Comment: Could you add corresponding controller code?